# Google Places API get a specific type for "car-repair" android

Tags: java, android-studio, google-places-api

There is a question already like this but was not answered. I'm using Google places API and it is returning all the places in my location. However I only want it to return a type for "car-repair" I'm close on getting this I feel but I'm not sure what to do next to get it to return type "car-repair" any help would be greatly appreciated thanks :)

My Code so far PlacPickerActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;


public class PlacePickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?type=car_repair&key=AIzaSyBKsTtLyMBQH8mhvbknJ4MvZwACotmeYO0";

    private TextView mName;
    private TextView mAddress;
    private TextView mAttributions;
    private TextView mNumber;
    private static final LatLngBounds Sligo = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(54.27, -8.47), new LatLng(54.27, -8.47));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_picker);
        mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mAttributions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        mNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        Button pickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickerButton);
        pickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                            new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                    intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(Sligo);

                    Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(PlacePickerActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
                        | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            final CharSequence name = place.getName();
            final CharSequence address = place.getAddress();
            final CharSequence formatted_phone_number = place.getPhoneNumber();
            String attributions = (String) place.getAttributions();
            if (attributions == null) {
                attributions = "";
            }

            mName.setText(name);
            mAddress.setText(address);
            mAttributions.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions));
            mNumber.setText(formatted_phone_number);


        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.truiton.placepicker">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBKsTtLyMBQH8mhvbknJ4MvZwACotmeYO0"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".PlacePickerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There is no point saying "Possible duplicate" if there is no answer on the other question as it is of no use.

Comment: I think the correct approach is to draw community attention to the initial question by placing a bounty. However, this requires at least 50 reputation.